# Log de erro pelo INI e no script

Tags: php, log

Tenho meu tratamento de erro usando as funções `set_error_handler, set_exception_handler, register_shutdown_function`, onde eu faço o debug e gravo a mensagem de erro com informações detalhadas e no *PHP.INI* habilitei a linha: `error_log = C:\webservice\PHP\log\erro.txt` para que o próprio php gere o seu log de erro.

O problema é que quando uso as funções citadas acima, o log não é criado pelo PHP.INI, se eu não usar as funções, então o PHP.INI cria o log. Parece que o log é criado ou por um ou outro e não juntos, e eu gostaria de debugar e criar meu log e permitir que o PHP crie o log próprio, tendo 2 logs de erro.

Queria saber se o uso das funções acima anulam a criação do log pelo PHP, ou há alguma linha no *INI* para configurar para que o PHP crie o próprio log independentemente de eu criar o meu.

Comment: ver (http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) 2º parágrafo. Se vc retornar false no callback ele faz o log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como é explicado no manual do PHP da [função set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-error-handler.php):

> É importante lembrar-se que o manipulador padrão de erros do PHP é
>   completamente ignorado.

Comment: Ocorre sobreposição? Há como contornar isso?

Comment: Sim ocorre. Não sei se há forma de contornar, mas parece-me que não.

Comment: @PapaCharlie dá uma vista de olhos nisto: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/php/ch13_04.htm